# Ram usage from memory profiler doesn't match the ram usage shown via top command in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, memory, memory-management

I am running a python script for recon procedure and I have decorated each function with `@profile` decorator from `memory_profiler` module in python.

So, the problem is when I try to get the memory usage via `memory_profiler`. It says that the memory usage via the program is around 3GB but when I use `top` command I see that the memory usage by the program is around 11GB. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Too bad you deleted the other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657865), I found a way to get the address of an *int* object. Note: I will delete this comment shortly.

Comment: @CristiFati you are funny :) Probably the only helpful person I found on StackOverflow. I know what I did was wrong but I hate StackOverflow now and will never ask for any help here. Good to see people like you still exist

Comment: @CristiFati I have undeleted the question in case you want to post an answer to help someone else who might want to solve something similar. If you are posting an answer to help me please don't I have already figured out a way to do that.

Comment: No need for expressions like "*I hate*" or similar, nor "*never ask again*". Millions of people (myself included) found lots of useful info here. You just need to get used to the site and the way you need to format your questions. I will probably update the other question tomorrow.