# Reading value stored in absolute memory address from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, cheat-engine

I used cheat engine to find an absolute address (See the attached image below)
[Memory address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqWNF.png)

Now I would like to know how can I read the value which is "1" from an address which is "0x14340A654"

I tried finding the same on StackOverflow and this is what I could gather.

```
from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof
from binascii import hexlify
a = 0x14340A654
print(hexlify(string_at(id(a), getsizeof(a))))
```

But this returns some gibberish like

```
b'030000000000000010bcabf2f87f0000020000000000000054a6400305000000'
```

Comment: Why do you use `id`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 what can be used there?

Comment: That's only going to read addresses in the Python process itself.  Usually a cheat engine is going to give the address of a game process.  You'll need a lot more complex code for that, using `ctypes` and OS system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


def get_long_data(long_obj):
    py_obj_header_size = sys.getsizeof(0)
    number_size = sys.getsizeof(long_obj) - py_obj_header_size
    number_address = id(long_obj) + py_obj_header_size
    return number_address, number_size, long_obj < 0


def hex_repr(number, size=0):
    format_base = "0x{{:0{:d}X}}".format(size)
    if number < 0:
        return ("-" + format_base).format(-number)
    else:
        return format_base.format(number)


def main():
    numbers = [0x00,
        0x01,
        -0x01,
        0xFF,
        0xFFFF,
        0x00FFFFFF,
        0x12345678,
        0x3FFFFFFF,
        0x40000000,
        0x1111111111
    ]
    for number in numbers:
        address, size, negative = get_long_data(number)
        print("Number: {:s}".format(hex_repr(number, size), size, negative))
        buf = ctypes.string_at(address, size)
        print("    Address: {:s}, Size: {:d}, Negative: {:},\n        Data: {:}".format(hex_repr(address, size=16), size, negative, buf))
        print("    ({:d}).to_bytes(): {:}".format(number, number.to_bytes(size, sys.byteorder, signed=(number < 0))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- ***get_long_data*** is the function that does the work (everything else it's just for display / test purposes)
- The address alone is kind of useless (if one wants to be able to reconstruct the number), that's why the size (in bytes), and the sign of the number are returned as well
- The code relies on [[Python 3]: **PyLongObject**](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLongObject)'s structure (most of *int* functionality is located in [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Objects/longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c)). Below it's its definition:

  ```
  struct _longobject {
      PyObject_VAR_HEAD
      digit ob_digit[1];
  };
  ```

  - The array at the end holds the actual number value (that's why numbers in *Python* can get so big)
  - For ***0***, `sys.getsizeof` only returns *PyObject_VAR_HEAD*'s size, that's used to get the array offset inside the structure
- [[Python 3]: int.**to_bytes**(*length, byteorder, *, signed=False*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) is used for verification, but note it will match our output **only if**: **`0 <= n < 2 ** 30`** (the method does some processing on the array contents, it doesn't directly store the raw data into the returned byte stream)
- It's visible that the bytes are (4 *byte*) reversed in the output buffer (***0x12345678*** is the most eloquent example), compared to the number's *hex* representation; that is because of ***little endianness*** (can check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior/38003729#38003729) for more details)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053657865>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Number: 0x0
>     Address: 0x0000000074C55318, Size: 0, Negative: False,
>         Data: b''
>     (0).to_bytes(): b''
> Number: 0x0001
>     Address: 0x0000000074C55338, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>     (1).to_bytes(): b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
> Number: -0x0001
>     Address: 0x0000000074C552F8, Size: 4, Negative: True,
>         Data: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>     (-1).to_bytes(): b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
> Number: 0x00FF
>     Address: 0x0000000074C572F8, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\xff\x00\x00\x00'
>     (255).to_bytes(): b'\xff\x00\x00\x00'
> Number: 0xFFFF
>     Address: 0x0000023286E3A6C8, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\xff\xff\x00\x00'
>     (65535).to_bytes(): b'\xff\xff\x00\x00'
> Number: 0xFFFFFF
>     Address: 0x0000023286C14FA8, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\xff\xff\xff\x00'
>     (16777215).to_bytes(): b'\xff\xff\xff\x00'
> Number: 0x12345678
>     Address: 0x0000023286DE4E88, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'xV4\x12'
>     (305419896).to_bytes(): b'xV4\x12'
> Number: 0x3FFFFFFF
>     Address: 0x000002328710C128, Size: 4, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\xff\xff\xff?'
>     (1073741823).to_bytes(): b'\xff\xff\xff?'
> Number: 0x40000000
>     Address: 0x000002328710C108, Size: 8, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>     (1073741824).to_bytes(): b'\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> Number: 0x1111111111
>     Address: 0x000002328710C148, Size: 8, Negative: False,
>         Data: b'\x11\x11\x11\x11D\x00\x00\x00'
>     (73300775185).to_bytes(): b'\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x00\x00\x00'
> ```

Comment: I will test your code when I get home and let you know. Thanks for your efforts @CristiFati